# Счетчик времени на С# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу небольшое приложение на WPF. Идея в такая: при запуске приложения, нужно запускать счетчик времени, который будет отмерять сколько секунд работает приложение.
Подскажите, с помощью каких инструментов/классов/элементов лучше это реализовать?

На текущий момент сделал так, но это не то что нужно:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
        timer.Start();


    }
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
    lebelTimer.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss");
    }
    TimeSpan time;
    DispatcherTimer timer;
    private void newGame_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       // timer = new DispatcherTimer(new TimeSpan(1000),;
        //time.TotalSeconds;

        lebelTimer.Content =time;
    }
```

p.s. данный код временно находится в классе MainWindow.cs, далее перенесу его в модели

Comment: Почему бы просто не запомнить время запуска приложения? Зачем вам таймер?

Comment: исключительно из-за дизайнерских соображений.

Comment: Время останавливать надо? [`Stopwatch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: нет, таймер будет работать до завершения программы

Comment: Спасибо, Stopwatch выручил!!!